# CSS transition and fixed positioning in Safari

Tags: safari, css-transitions, css-position, parallax

I'm having some issues with a website that only occur in Safari. I'm running version 5.1.7 (7534.57.2) on a Mac.

You can view the site here: http://mcad.edu/annual-report-2011-12/.

The website is parallax scrolling, with a relative positioned content div that holds everything, including the 3 parallax scrolling backgrounds which are all fixed, top and left set to 0.

Within the fixed parallax background containers, colorized images fade into full color images when a user mouses over them. For each "image", there are two divs stacked, each with background images that are positioned by background-position. The div on the bottom has the colorized image. The div on top has the full color image as a background and has its opacity set to 0 until mouseover. The fade is achieved using a CSS transition on the opacity property so that the top div becomes visible.

So, in Safari only, when I mouse over any of these divs, the transition occurs smoothly but all of the content in the same parallax scrolling background div shifts/jumps in the process. If I remove the CSS transition, this does not occur.

I think that it might have something to do with the transition/webkit-transition property not playing nicely with a fixed position container in Safari. However, all of the issues I've found that relate to that are from 2010 and mention a Safari bug that I assume has been fixed…two years later. But maybe not.

There's also another issue with the Catalyst section (3rd dot down on the right navigation). These animated images work as links in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but not Safari. Any ideas?

Comment: Solved the flickering transition problem by adding -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0); to the affected divs. Still stuck on the second issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with a fixed position and transition-duration for a header menu I've created. When a visitor scrolls down, the menu has a box shadow that fades into place. Well when this is viewed on safari in a MacOS, I get a weird sliding in issue. To easily fix this, after spending way to much time searching for answers, I'm removing the transition effect for macs. This fixes the slide in issue but gets rid of the transition effect sadly.

So as you were speculating, it probably is the transition duration on your project as well. The best thing for this would probably be to make a Mac-Safari CSS file, get rid of the transition-duration for that particular area and move on with your project.

Best I can suggest for now. Hope it helps.